# Newton-Raphson problem (I think) on a calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across the following equation: $$\boxed{20=\frac{230\sqrt{2}}{2\pi(1+\cos(X))}}$$ with $X$ being in degrees.

Now, this is easily solvable, however if I'm being lazy and use the "solve for $X$" option on a Casio calculator (of 2 different models) the result will vary wildly depending on the reference number given when using this feature (I got result varying from 127.85 which is the correct answer to 999954 when starting from a blank memory or 0).

I assume this has to do with a limitation of the Newton - Raphson method the calculator uses to solve for $X$ (or in Casio's implementation of it) for trig functions, but since I can't say I really understand Newton- Raphson method I can't even start to figure out where the problem lies.

I am curious , however would appreciate a layman's explanation of this phenomena.

Thanks

Comment: Newton's method requires derivatives and division. Numerical differentiation can cause some problems depending on the function.

Comment: Blame the calculator. `999954 when starting from a blank memory` strongly hints an undefined behavior.

Comment: Cosine being periodic, your equation has infinitely many solutions. Which one an algorithm will converge to will depend on the "reference number".

Answer (score 2):

The problem as written has no real solution. The given solution $127.85°$ actually corresponds to $\sqrt2$ being in the denominator on the right side. In the following I assume that $\sqrt2$ in the denominator was meant.

Take the derivative of your function and note that this is zero at a starting value of zero. Then the N-R method has to divide by zero. Frankly, I'm surprised the calculator gave you anything at all when the initial value was zero.

I would find two values in the range you want where the function is oppositely signed, then start the N-R method with a guess in-between. If an iterate goes out of the range between the initial guesses, then count it as a failure. In that case either try a different guess or switch to a slower but more robust method such as the secant method.

Comment: It is amazing to notice that nobody said that there is no real solution.

Comment: This is because I took the OP's word for it. The inconsistency appears to be a result of misplacing the square root of 2 in either the problem statement or the calculation, see the introduction I added.

Answer (score 1):

Working with radians, consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{115 \sqrt{2}}{\pi  \left(1+\cos \left(x\frac{\pi  }{180}\right)\right)}-20$$

Its minimum value is attained when $x=0$ and $f(0)=\frac{115}{\sqrt{2} \pi }-20 =5.88409 ~>0$.

So, beside the fact that there is an infinite number of roots, they are imaginary.

Let $x=iy$ and consider
$$g(y)=\frac{115 \sqrt{2}}{\pi  \left(1+\cosh \left(y\frac{\pi  }{180}\right)\right)}-20$$ or better, using the half-angle formula
$$h(y)=\cosh ^2\left(y\frac{\pi  }{360}\right)-\frac{23}{4 \sqrt{2} \pi }$$ and since $\cosh(t)> 0\forall t$, it suffice to look for the solution of
$$j(y)=\cosh \left(y\frac{\pi  }{360}\right)-\sqrt{\frac{23}{4 \sqrt{2} \pi } }$$

Assuming that $y$ is large, make the approximation
$$\frac 12 \exp \left(y\frac{\pi  }{360}\right)-\sqrt{\frac{23}{4 \sqrt{2} \pi } }=0 \implies y_0=\frac{360}{\pi }\log \left(\sqrt{\frac{23}{\sqrt{2} \pi }}\right)$$ Now, using Newton method, the iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & y_n \\
 0 & 94.205190 \\
 1 & 66.770062 \\
 2 & 59.892558 \\
 3 & 59.453718 \\
 4 & 59.451953
\end{array}
\right)$$

So, one solution is $X \sim (59.452)(\pi/180)i\approx1.0376i$ in radians.

Comment: @OscarLanzi. Thankis for the point and the edit. Cheers :-)